# Remove PWA Site that has Missing Database

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, sharepoint, iis-6, microsoft-project

Okay, so, we did something bad. :-\

When we were first learning about SharePoint and MS Project, we created a 2 or three 'training'/'test' sites (say, PWA_Test and PWA_Train). These, of course, needed their own databases and such. Well, months later, after we got the full enchilada up and "running", our DBA was going to write some backup routines for our SharePoint/Project sites and decided we no longer needed the old test and training databases so he deleted them.

We didn't notice anything wrong as we never went to those sites anymore. Then we had an error on our production project site and checked the event log to find that it was utterly filled with SharePoint errors claiming that syncing failed because they can't find their respective databases. By this time our backups of those old training and test databases no longer existed as they were a "waste of space".

So now we can't figure out how to remove the old sites without, basically, wiping the machine clean and starting fresh (which isn't really an option at all at the moment).

Any idea how to properly remove these old sites or "turn them off"?

I really appreciate it, in advance, if you do.

Thanks.

Comment: You should rollback your edit - the original title was correct. The PWA site is a different beast to a typical SharePoint site.

Comment: BTW Alex, we're waiting for a good time to try out your suggestion, so, I haven't forgotten about you. Just wanna verify it works before deciding to choose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

PWA sites can be managed from the Shared Services Administration page under "Project Web Access". This is where PWA sites (and their databases) are managed and should have been deleted from.

SharePoint and Project Server don't particularly like their databases being managed directly from SQL and deleting them this way is a big no-no. Other databases such as the SSP and SharePoint configuration database will still hold a reference and look for them.

If you're lucky, you may be able to delete the PWA sites from this admin screen even though the databases are missing. Otherwise, you will need to restore them and delete them from here "the supported way".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above,

If you really find you can't get the sites to delete without the content databases in any way try this:

Make a new Web App with a Site in the Site Collection - just a blank one - (Verify it's working)
Backup the new web app Content Database
Restore a copy of the Content Database to where the other sites are looking for them
Verify you can browse to the site
Delete the sites through stsadm or Central Admin